# Android Emulator v/s Phone

Tags: java, android, adb

I'm runnning an app that I've created that use the Google Maps API.

It works as expected on the emulator , that I'm using , however , the graphics seem to render in a different way on my phone.

Please see the following images for reference

[image: on my HTC Explorer , the Bevel effect isn't visible]
[image: on my emulator , the Bevel effect is perfectly visible]
[image: This is the image i'm repeating - its being used in the background of the view]

Here's my activity.xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />



  <TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView1"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="30dp"
     android:background="@drawable/repeat"
     android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
     android:text=""
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" /> 


   <com.google.android.maps.MapView
       android:id="@+id/mapView"
       android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:enabled="true"
       android:clickable="true"
       android:apiKey="--private--" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Why is the same image being observed differently - one on the device, and one on the emulator ?

Answer (score 0):

For testing on real hardware you need to use a key different from the debug key. I think you are using a debug keystore.

Visit : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/v1/?csw=1#getfingerprint

Read that paragraph on google.

Is important that the application is exported as a signed application with the same key used for the google api (and NOT the debug key).

For create a valid read that paragraph:

Visit : http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html#releasemode

and then use the same key to obtain the google maps api key.

Once you have the key for your application you can export a signed application by clicking with right button of your mouse on the project select Android Tools and then Export as a signed application package and follow the wizard (probably you can create a new key using that wizard).

hope that help.